# What does str.encode expect as input?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

I was hoping to use `unicode` instead of `str` for all strings in my project.  I am trying to use the `str.encode` method but can't make out from the documentation what the `encode` method exactly does or expects as input.

The Greek small letter pi is U+03C0, and when encoded in UTF-8 is 0xCF 0x80.  I get the following:

```
>>> s1 = '\xcf\x80'
>>> s1.encode('utf-8','ignore')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 1, in <module>
    s1.encode('utf-8','ignore')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried it for:

```
>>> s2='\x03\xc0'

>>> s2.encode('utf-8','ignore')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#62>", line 1, in <module>
    s2.encode('utf-8','ignore')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What does `encode` expect as input, and why does the 'ignore' option not ignore the error?  I tried 'replace' and that also does not cover up the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `str` is a byte string (encoded). You can decode it to unicode object:

```
>>> s1 = '\xcf\x80'  # string literal (str)
>>> s1.decode('utf-8')
u'\u03c0'
```

For unicode object, you can do encode:

```
>>> u1 = u'\u03c0'  # unicode literal (unicode)  U+03C0
>>> u1.encode('utf-8')
'\xcf\x80'
```